# How to add new users in sharepoint which tables have to use

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How to add new users in sharepoint which tables have to use

what is the procedur for adding new users in sharepoint

thanks 
Narasimha

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean programmatically? There is an example in [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/karthick/archive/2006/03/16/553026.aspx):

```
SPWeb web = new SPSite("Site URL").OpenWeb();
SPUserInfo[] userInfo = new SPUserInfo[1];
userInfo[0].Email = "email@microsoft.com";
userInfo[0].LoginName = @"domain\username";
userInfo[0].Name = "username";
userInfo[0].Notes = "Test";
web.Roles["Reader"].Users.AddCollection(userInfo);
```

You may want to take a look at this forum thread as well: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/db46ab8f-9594-4878-9bab-a18fe3fba959/